# Cakephp Year format

Tags: cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

I am using form helper in Cakephp 2.x

```
<?php echo $this->Form->year('Album.year', 1950, date('Y'), array('type' => 'select', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => "textbox", 'empty' => 'Select Year')); ?>
```

This code outputs

```
<select id="AlbumYearYear" class="textbox" name="data[Album][year][year]">
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
</select>
```

In this way . while other fields are outputting as `name="data[Model][source_id]"`. Like this

How would I remove second [year] in above mentioned element because its causing error in saving `$this-request->data` as `year is array element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing

$this->Form->year('Album.year'

do

$this->Form->year('Album'